# Specify which emulator to use in Visual Studio when solution has multiple startup projects

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a solution that contains a Xamarin forms app and a WebAPI 2 service that provides the back-end to that app.

When I set the solution to have a single startup project, I can choose which device/emulator the project should be deployed to using a dropdown in the toolbar, but when I select multiple start up projects I can no longer choose the emulator/device (the drop down list of emulators disappears). Because there is no deployment target the build then fails.

Is there another way to specify which emulator/device the Android project should launch on (maybe in code, e.g. in the project file?).

Comment: I have this same problem.  I don't know why more people aren't questioning this.

Comment: My multiple startup projects setup is working fine now.  It's just deploying to the last used emulator used.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this some time ago but didn't find any real solution other than just opening the solution twice and running the Web API and app with a single startup project.

Most of the time, I just run one project without debugging (ctrl+F5).